# Shoud I import "drive.mount" for all running code?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Running Colab code, I want to import my own python module in google drive.
In this situation...

Should I import my module every running code???

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

import os
import sys
sys.path.insert (0, "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do like this

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

if you need to upload your module from local drive:

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
   print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

or you can refer this 
[Refer this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uvHuizCBqFgvbCwEhK7FvU8JW0AfxgJw)

Comment: Check my answer edits if you want to upload the whole module

Comment: Thank you. You are great answer. Thank you. I Got it